# Can MK+"Ord is almost-huge"+MM$^{++}$ be new standard foundations instead of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

I'll try to explain what this looks like to a non-expert in set theory. First, $MK$ is just a second-order $ZFC$, and there are moments when we would like to use second-order statements, for example, to write down schemes of axioms as axioms. Second, in this question, "$Ord$ is almost-huge" is in some way a union of two statements: "$Ord$ is weakly compact cardinal ($WCC$)" and "$Ord$ is Vopěnka cardinal ($VC$)" (The almost-huge cardinal is the smallest weakly compact Vopěnka cardinal I know of).

$MK$ + "$Ord$ is $WCC$" is a nice theory in many ways, it is not strong enough to deal with "foundation-inspired problems", but it provides good behavior for first-order logics with sentences of set-length; since the least $WCC$ is not the least Mahlo/inaccessible cardinal, it allows one to safely use any category-theoretic construction for small entities. There are also nice connections to Quine's New Foundations and positive set theory, which has a true Universe. "$Ord$ is $VC$" provides Vopěnka's principle, which has phenomenal implications for logic, category theory, and the reflection principle (global reflection principle, structural reflection), nuff said.

MM$^{++}$ is the most special among this trinity, and the least understood by me. It is important because it makes important mathematics independent of ZFC dependent, and is presented as a solution to the continuum hypothesis (there is an beautiful paper by Matteo Viale on this topic, but the second half of it is not so clear to me). Morally, I take it as "Universe is as thick as possible".

Besides the main question, I would also like to ask what is forcing and what does MM say about it if we look at *models as representations* of abstract sets (without the Baire theorem, in particular)?

Comment: "I would also like to ask what is forcing" - You know what an almost-huge cardinal is, but you don't know what forcing is?

Comment: @Alex: The real question is how does one know about forcing axioms, but not about forcing?

Comment: @AlexKruckman I meant how forcing is worth looking at, so that believing or not believing propositions about it has more motivation than just an instrumental view of it.

Comment: The premise of the question feels really weird to me. I get an impression that the only reason you propose this specific theory is that it settles a lot of questions which are independent of ZFC. But that has very little to do with what it would take for it to become a "standard foundation", which is more about it being theory which (a bulk of) people can agree is a natural set of assumptions to take. The fact even you as the OP propose an axiom which you yourself admit you don't understand well makes me very doubtful this theory could meet that burden.

Answer (score 6):

Your stated motivation for considering Morse-Kelley set theory is that the second-order language allows us easily to express schemes of (first-order) axioms. That seems fine, but this motivation really only justifies the strictly weaker theory of Gödel-Bernays set theory, which is a second-order set theory exactly enabling us to express the schemes of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory in single sweeping statements, in just the way you mention.

But GBC is strictly weaker than KM and different in character. One of the standard ways to build a model of Gödel-Bernays set theory, for example, is to take all the definable classes over a model of ZFC. This is how one can show that GBC is conservative over ZFC for assertions about sets. (For global choice, one should start with a model of V=HOD(a) or add a global well-order generically.) In these models, every class is first-order definable from parameters.

What I would like to mention about this situation, however, is that in this case, one can refute the axiom "Ord is Weakly Compact". This is the main theorem of my article with Ali Enayat.

**Theorem (Enayat+Hamkins).** If all classes are definable (allowing parameters), then Ord is not weakly compact. Specifically, if $M$ is a model of ZFC.

1. The tree property fails in $M$ at Ord for definable classes. There is a definable Ord-tree in $M$ with no definable branch.
2. The partition property fails in $M$ at Ord for definable classes. There is a definable 2-coloring $c:[X]^2\to 2$ of some definable proper class $X$ with no definable proper class monochromatic class.
3. The compactness property for $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$ fails in $M$ for definable classes. There is a definable $\mathcal{L}_{\infty,\omega}$ theory in $M$ such that every set-sized subtheory is realized by a definable class model, but the whole theory is not realized in any definable class model of $M$.

Our paper is available at:

- *Enayat, Ali; Hamkins, Joel David*, [**ZFC proves that the class of ordinals is not weakly compact for definable classes**](https://doi.org/10.1017/jsl.2017.75), J. Symb. Log. 83, No. 1, 146-164 (2018). [ZBL1447.03016](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1447.03016). [arxiv:1610.02729](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02729).

Therefore, if one wants to adopt "Ord is weakly compact" as a fundamental axiom, one needs to provide a better justification than you have for classes, and specifically for nondefinable classes.